# Render information from mongo with pug

Tags: node.js

I try to create small web app, but have some problem with render information from db.
This is my handler from viewController.js.

```
    exports.getInventory = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const printers = await Printer.find();
  console.log(printers);
  const columnName = Object.keys(Printer.schema.tree).splice(0, 10);
  //
  res.status(200).render('inventory', {
    title: 'Inventory',
    isInventory: true,
    columnName,
    printers,
  });
});
```

I use mongoose to take data from db and saved it into printers. When I received printers variable from db, it’s look like this:

```
    [
  {
    ContractNumber: 'Addition #3',
    Location: 'N/A',
    Owner: 'N/A',
    Phone: 'N/A',
    _id: 5f34fd0375d06e18a09f8351,
    Name: 'Xerox B405_2787',
    IP: '172.16.202.233',
    Model: 'Xerox C7020',
    SNInventory: '789653444',
    EquipmentType: 'productive',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I don’t know how to render it from pug. How can I get key and value and put them into certain position?

my template

```
    extends base
//- 
block content
    table.table.table-sm.table-hover
        thead
            tr  
                th(scope='col') #
                each i in columnName
                    th(scope='col')= i

                
        tbody
            tr
                th(scope='row') 1
                each i in printers
                    td i
                    
            tr
                th(scope='row') 2
                td 1
                td 2
                td 3
                td 4
                td 5
                td 6
                td 7
                td 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const printerData = ... // Your Mongoose Array of Printer Data
res.render('inventory', printerData);
```

in your inventory.pug

```js
extends base
block content
   table#mainTable
      - let keys = Object.keys(printerData[0]);
      thead
         tr
            each key in keys
               th= key
      tbody
         each printer in printerData
            tr
               each key in keys
                  - let value = printer[key];
                  td= value;
```

This works by creating an array of keys, then looping through each item in the `printerData` array and each key in the `keys` array, and matching them up.

Happy Coding!